# Dose anyone knows why this addEventlitsner callback could running correctly?

Tags: javascript, image, callback, addeventlistener

i just wanna tried to used an addEventListener on image DOM element, 
but, no matter what type of listsner i used on it,
the callback always works fine no matter image dom element is loaded or not.

my code as below:

```
var img = document.querySelectorAll('img');

//theoretically, this callback shouldn't work, but it did.
img[0].addEventListener('no matter what my typing here, it still works', callStr('ok'));

function callStr(str){
   console.log(str);
}
```

codeoen here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvZxbB?editors=1111

Does anyone knows why?
Many Thanks.

Comment: The line shown calls the `callStr()` function *immediately* and passes its return value (`undefined`) to `addEventListener()`. That is, your code is the equivalent of `callStr('ok'); img[0].addEventListener('no matter what my typing here, it still works', undefined);`. (This is not what the word "correctly" means.)

Comment: Why do you think it's running correctly? It's logging `ok` before you do anything that triggers an event.

Comment: Your code is immediately invoking the `callStr('ok')` and returning `undefined`, Ideally, it should wait for said event to happen and then trigger the callback.

Comment: Thanks for the exsist question marked,
link as below for those who might need it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020769/addeventlistener-with-ajax-not-working-well